# Algorithm to detect doors and windows in an image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

I'm working on an educational project where I need to detect objects, mainly doors and windows. I have tried to find specific algorithms to do this.

This is the first step in a project to detect all objects and let a user choose the object he wants. Then in the next step the system will define edges of the object accurately.

I want to detect objects by their color variety with background or with overlapping objects. I need an algorithm to start with. I started learning color spaces and I chose hvs color space. I read many papers and I know how they work,  but I'm still confused and don't know what algorithm will really help.

Comment: there is no reliable universal method of object detection/classification . You need go through the trial&error. If you got experience then you will have feeling which algorithm will likely help to solve which task but the trial&error is usually still there... If you want to help which direction to go **You Always have to provide some sample of input images** you want to work on because each type of images are different and methods used are therefore also different. From vague description window/door we know nothing about the image itself (composition,colors,illumination,noise,blur,background)

Comment: as Spektre said the algorithm will be specific for your situation. Are set properties for doors? For instance the system only works in one building where all doors are grey with a small window in them at the same location. This would mean you could use combinations of template matching, color matching, bounding box, etc. Windows are even more complex because you can see anything through them. They can be various shapes and sizes, there could be trees or a parking lot or anything on the other side of it. Maybe finding windows with closed blinds might be easier. its all specific to your porblem

Comment: the image will be taken by the user . so it could be any door/window. there is no specifications for them , they might be indoor images or outdoor images with any shape/color of door/window. thank you for replaying

Answer (score 0):

You can use any segmentation algorithm. 
You will need to find features from images to use in segmentation, a good approach for feature selection is by using any deep learning technique,  i would recommend try CNN, you will find a builtin library "matconvnet" "http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/" for implementing CNN in MATLAB.
you can also find few already build models for segmentation using CNN here http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/pretrained/